# Firebase Cloud Functions: Send Email via Authentication System

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

Firebase Authentication has a built in email service. Is it possible to fire an auth based email via Cloud Functions (admin js sdk)?

Seems like I should be able to trigger an email from `noreply@my-domain.com` with a custom `oob` code which I could then use to drive my (client-side) application.

My use case would be, when a new order `.collection("orders").doc(uid)` has its `stage` field updated/changed to `'submitted'` I would like to notify a user via email that a new order is submitted. Maybe even use the oob code to mark as `'processed'`?

...just trying to avoid using a 3rd party email service altogether.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, their API does not appear to support emailing users in your project. However, they have sample code for cloudfunctions to email users you can easily tweak for your needs: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users

Comment: I think you're right, their admin sdk does not offer this, however it looks like the js sdk does offer [user.sendEmailVerification(actionCodeSettings)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#sendEmailVerification). I'll hack at it...

Comment: went ahead and accepted. ...I just realized that my payment processor will be the one to notify me (via email) when an 'order' is 'processed'.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `MailChimp` to do what you are asking, since like Miles says, you will need to do a workaround in order to fix this.

I have been using `MailChimp` my self to send emails to each user registered in my app , i have setup a couple of emails in mailchimp and i just add to the list all the users that register to my app, so the first message will be the welcome message, then after 2 days another email and so on, you can trigger an email whenever you want, since the doc is not that clear i have made a tutorial on how to integrate it with Android.

you can find that tutorial [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I2x2mlbDcpI) , the only thing is that is in spanish, sorry.

The idea is simple, just get your users email throught `FirebaseAuth` , pass that email to the mailchimp query , and then setup an email from the mailchimp website

Comment: will do. ty. was hoping to use the firebase email system - even though the functionality is not advertised...

Comment: yes, i know, having all the things in firebase is the best thing since is more confortable, but thanks that this answer is a hint of help for you :)